# using mod_fcgid instead of mod_cgi

Tags: php, apache-2.2

What all should i do to use mod_fcgid instead of mod_php on ubuntu and centos. what are the main benefits and difference's between two

Comment: mod_cgi or mod_php? You changed your mind between typing the question and entering the details.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming question and answer site. You are asking a question about software choice and configuration, not programming. Please use ServerFault, the system administration question and answer site, if you can't answer this by doing your own research.